# How do I install libmysqlclient21 on debian:buster-slim based Docker image?

Tags: mysql, docker, debian

I have a Docker image that is based on debian:buster-slim and I am deploying my application to it which connects to a mysql database.
I have installed mysql-client:
`apt-get install -y default-mysql-client`.

My dbdriver requires the 'libmysqlclient.so.21' library which weirdly does not come with the default-mysql-client library. So I tried to install it separately using `apt-get install libmysqlclient21` but I get:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient21
```

After some research, I found out that people are installing `default-libmysql-dev` but this did not solve my problem either.

What can I do to be able to download this package on a Docker container? Specifically, on a debian based container.

Comment: You might search using https://packages.debian.org/ to try to find the package you need.  I don't immediately see a runtime package that includes any version of `libmysqlclient.so.*`; you may need to rebuild the image using the target Debian release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to install it only after adding the mysql software repository:

```
cd /tmp && wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_${MYSQL_VERSION}_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_${MYSQL_VERSION}_all.deb
apt update
apt-get install -y libmysqlclient21
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by [YanaT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15638214/yanat) is mostly correct. Those commands from above:

```
cd /tmp && wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_${MYSQL_VERSION}_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_${MYSQL_VERSION}_all.deb
apt update
apt-get install -y libmysqlclient21
```

However with an older version of this package (i.e. the value of `MYSQL_VERSION` above) I suddenly started getting the following error:

```
# apt-get install -y libmysqlclient21
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient21
```

Only by using the absolute latest version of the `mysql-apt-config` package (listed at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) did the `apt-get install -y libmysqlclient21` command succeed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).